# Android MD5 debug fingerprint missing from debug keystore

Tags: android, debugging, md5, fingerprint

I have built a new development machine and installed Android SDK.  I tried to obtain the Android MD5 debug fingerprint but cannot seem to get it to generate.  I have deleted the debug.keystore to create a new one and only the SHA1 fingerprint is present.

Please advise

Here is my debug.keystore contents:

c:>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool" -list -keystore "C:\users\me\.android\debug.keystore
Enter keystore password:

***********  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

androiddebugkey, May 2, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): F8:A5:0E:DD:61:5D:FC:86:D9:33:13:48:30:E0:EF:37:
47:81:60:EF

c:>

I am running Windows7 64 bit.  The MD5 fingerprints are also not showing in my production keystore that I restored from a backup from the previous system (WindowsXP SP3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  There is another post on SO ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262695/how-to-get-md5-from-debug-keystore-file)) that states that rolling back from

jdk-7-ea-bin-b140-windows-x64

to

jdk-6u25-windows-x64

resolves the issue.  THIS WORKED FOR ME!

dranfi, your answer is technically correct, but that's what I used in the first place.

jdk-7-ea-bin-b140-windows-x64 obviously has some issues to resolve.

I perhaps should have stated the javaSDK version in the first place -sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:-

c:>cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool" -list -keystore "C:\users\me.android\debug.keystore"

*note :- Replace me with your username

after this you get MD5 ,
Copy that MD5 paste it in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup
 and generate API KEY for map, use that API KEY in main.xml file.
May it helps you. 
Reply if not works

Comment: You should use the api key in maifest as -     android:apiKey="@string/map_api_key"

Answer (score 0):

Your command yhould be for the debug certificate :
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool" -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\users\me\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
(from : http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Comment: I still get only the SHA1 fingerprint:                                                                                          
C:\Users\me>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool" -list -alias andro
iddebugkey -keystore "C:\users\me\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass andro
id -keypass android
androiddebugkey, May 2, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): F8:A5:0E:DD:61:5D:FC:86:D9:33:13:48:30:E0:EF:37:
47:81:60:EF

C:\Users\me>

Comment: Furthermore:C:\Users\me>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool" -list -alias andro
iddebugkey -keystore "C:\users\me\.android\debug.keystore"
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\users\me\.a
ndroid\debug.keystore

C:\Users\me>

Comment: For somer reason, the '\\' has to be escaped in the editor.  I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 (1.7.0) changed the default output from the keytool command. See [JDK 7 changes keytool output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690293/jdk-7-changes-keytool-output) .

Answer (score 0):

Add the -v option to print all possible fingerprints, so complete command will look like this, then select the MD5 output:

```
keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```