# Obtaining Google Maps API key

Tags: android, google-maps, md5

I'm using Windows 7.

I have tried several times with the debug.keystore with appears in c:\users\YOURUSER.android\ using the command:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore c:\Users\YOURUSER\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

It gives me a MD5, but then I go to Google MD5 registration page and it sais it is not a valid fingerprint.

I searched for more information, and I finally created a new debug.keystore into c:\users\YOURUSER\ to avoid rewriting the original one. I used this command:

```
keytool -genkey -keypass android -keystore c:\users\YOURUSER\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -validity 10000 -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"
```

It works, so I use the previous command to get the MD5, and it gives me a new MD5. Then I go to Google again and the same problem: "not a valid fingerprint".

The I made a second attempt. This is what I did then:
1) Opened a Windows7 terminal, went to c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin\
2) Wrote command:

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\eclipse\my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

3) Then I tried to get the MD5 code from my keystore, using comand:

```
keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore c:\eclipse\my-release-key.keystore
```

and writing the password I am asked. It gives me a MD5.

4) I go to maps api key sign up and write the MD5. "FINGERPRINT NOT VALID"

I don't know what the problem is. And I am supposed to do this for every app I program? What a headache!

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803944/find-the-key-hash-for-a-signed-app/5805214#5805214

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863201/android-md5-debug-fingerprint-missing-from-debug-keystore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you get the MD5 and not the SHA1 fingerprint? Tryed the -v option?
see: [How can I get the MD5 fingerprint from Java's keytool, not only SHA-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1)

Comment: Correct, all my trouble came from using java jdk1.7. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

google maps has deprecated its previous version API v1 and introduced a new version of google maps API v2.

previously we generated md5 key but now we need to generate sha-1 fingerprint certificate.

The Maps API key is based on a short form of your application's digital certificate, known as its SHA-1 fingerprint. The fingerprint is a unique text string generated from the commonly-used SHA-1 hashing algorithm. Because the fingerprint is itself unique, Google Maps uses it as a way to identify your application.

please go through the links it could help you

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code

also see the same kind of post in stack over flow

[How to implement Google Maps new version of API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912336/how-to-implement-google-maps-new-version-of-api-v2)

Answer (score 0):

1. In command line  you need to open Java-> jdk-> bin 
   as for me  it  is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin"
2. There is "keytool" program which u need. In command line enter "cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin"
3. And enter "keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\John\.android\debug.keystore"
   So the final string in command line must look like:
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\John\.android\debug.keystore". Whare usually u need only to change the name "John"

There will be SHA-1, MD5, etc

Finally, go to Google Access API [google access api](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:32596228624%3aaccess)