# GoogleMaps not loading properly

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to change my GoogleMaps view between StreetView and Satellite via menubutton.
The code I have used is:

```
    case R.id.item_satellite_view:
            mapView.setStreetView(false);
            mapView.setSatellite(true);
            mapView.invalidate();
            return true;

    case R.id.item_street_view:
            mapView.setSatellite(false);
            mapView.setStreetView(true);
            mapView.invalidate();           
            return true;
```

The problem I am getting is the map only shows blank squares with X in it.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for a Google Maps API key. See [my own question time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603577/obtaining-google-maps-api-key)