# Problems getting MD5 fingerprint

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I try to generate a MD5 fingerprint to obtain a map api key using Java7.

I do it on the way, described at [developer page](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint)

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool" -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

The problem is, I'm getting SHA1 Fingerprint and not MD5

```
androiddebugkey, 01.08.2011, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Any ideas why?

Thnak you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting. Well, you can get the entire cert information using this command.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore
```

You'll need to enter `android` as the password when prompted. That will give you everything in the keystore, which should only be one certificate rather than looking for a specific alias. It should show you both an MD5 and a SHA1 fingerprint. Give that a try and let me know.

The only thing I can think of is that jdk1.7's keytool gets information differently than jdk1.6(returns SHA1 by default?). This is just a guess and has not been verified but it is the only thing I can really think of.

**Edit**: It appears my guess might be correct. [JDK 7 changes keytool output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690293/jdk-7-changes-keytool-output)

Comment: I wouldn't go with MD5withRSA, just MD5 perhaps. Failing that, I would just run the command I gave initially, it should list both of them (as well as other certificate information).

Comment: unfortunate, but what about my first command suggested? or even just throwing a -v into the original command like so `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\keytool" -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android`

Comment: adding -v helped as well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot.. keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore command helped me..

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved the problem with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262695/how-to-get-md5-from-debug-keystore-file)

I changed my call to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\keytool" and ... everything works

Comment: I wonder if there's something about jdk1.7 that gets the finger prints differently.