# Facebook App Android running on Emulator but not on Device

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I downloaded a facebook app source from the internet opened it in eclipse and ran it. It runs fine on the emulator but not on the device which i have for debugging.

There are suggestions that it is an SSO issue but i cant figure it out.

I am getting my debug key by the following method

on CMD

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Mohammad Umair Khan\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 -out "C:\Users\Mohammad Umair Khan\key.txt"
```

after entering android in password, I get a key which i put on the developers.facebook.com application page

still i am not able to run on my device but it is working fine on emulator.

any suggestions ?

**EDIT:**
It is definitly an issue with the keyhash. I got the key from adb logcat and placed it on to facebook app page and it worked like a charm.

still anyone with a solution to obtaining the correct debug key .. ???

Comment: How about some more Information. What isn't working? Does the App start? Which error throws the Facebook SDK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690293/jdk-7-changes-keytool-output

Comment: the application starts, when i press the button which leads to authentication, the facebook app starts and then simply returns to the main screen, behavior similar to finish(); in android...

Answer (score 0):

SSO stands for single sign on. It means suppose you have Fb app for android installed in your phone and you are online in it, you tend to be online everywhere which uses fb login. Try uninstalling the original app and try your code. Also check for the Android Key HAsh and make sure you have entered it in the facebook app page where you get your app ID.

Comment: i also made sure that i have entered the correct appid and hashkey